# Left justifying in one frame of beamer

Tags: beamer, alignment

I have two itemizes in one frame of beamer. But the top one contain double columns, which makes it too wide. Thus, the bottom one is not aligned with the top one, and it seems that center aligned is defaulted for the bottom one. So how can I make it  left justifying for the two itemizes? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Without the code that produces this example, it is impossible to answer you.

Comment: Your columns are too wide. Either reduce them from `.5\textwidth` to something like `.48\textwidth` or use `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You columns are too wide. Their combined width and the space in between the columns is wider than the available textwidth of your frame. To fix this you can use `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]` and make the columns a bit smaller to perserve some inter-column space.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
image
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
image
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great thank！It really works.